# Command line shortcut to connect to a docker container

Tags: bash, docker, containers

Is there any shortcut command to connect to a docker container without running `docker exec -it 'container_id' bash` every time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a shorter *command line shortcut* to:

1. Check if a container is running
2. If running, connect to a running container using `docker exec -it <container> bash` command:

**Script `docker-enter`:**

```
#!/bin/bash

name="${1?needs one argument}"

containerId=$(docker ps | awk -v app="$name:" '$2 ~ app{print $1}')

if [[ -n "$containerId" ]]; then
    docker exec -it $containerId bash
else
    echo "No docker container with name: $name is running"
fi
```

Then run it as:

```
docker-enter webapp
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I made it into a function and removed the ":" after "name":

    function docker_exec {
  name="${1?needs one argument}"
  containerId=$(docker ps | awk -v app="$name" '$2 ~ app{print $1}')

  if [[ -n "$containerId" ]]; then
    docker exec -it $containerId bash
  else
    echo "No docker container with name: $name is running"
  fi
}

Comment: Giving up on formatting code here (even after I RTFM). Here's the gist:

https://gist.github.com/tmuth/29533265de89cc65124fd215c8ff9494#file-docker_exec-sh

Comment: I cobbled something together from multiple sources which works perfect, it let's you exec or log the container with the Name and not the ID: https://github.com/mattiLeBlanc/docker-aliases

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following alias on OS X:

```
alias dex='function _dex(){ docker exec -i -t "$(basename $(pwd) | tr -d "[\-_]")_$1_1" /bin/bash -c "export TERM=xterm; exec bash" };_dex'
```

In the same directory as my docker-files, I run "dex php" to enter the PHP container.

Comment: Thanks for this! Exactly what I wanted. I did have to modify the command to remove the `-` from the `tr` part because my directory has a `-` in it, but otherwise it works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

If random id is complicated. Start container with name `docker run --name test image` and connect with its name `docker exec -it test bash`.